# Skype does not appear in panel (elementaryOS 0.2)

Tags: elementary-os, skype, panel, qt4

I had removed skype panel icon with this method : https://askubuntu.com/questions/7479/how-can-i-remove-the-skype-panel-icon-in-ubuntu-12-04-and-earlier/118979#118979

It worked fine, and I was using skype-wrapper to have skype in my messaging menu.. Then skype-wrapper has stopped working and I wanted to have my skype icon back..

I have reinstalled sni-qt (I never removed it but anyway I did reinstall it.) and I have reinstalled skype too (following this link :https://askubuntu.com/questions/68616/i-installed-sni-qt-and-there-is-no-indicator-for-skype-how-do-i-fix-this) but it didn't do anything..

(I will add that I don't need to whitelist it in dconf editor because I'm using elementaryOS Luna 2.0 and doesn't have a whitelist but a blacklist (which I have checked))

What package sould I add or update ? I tried to update QT libraries unsuccessfully..

Cheers!

ElementaryOS 2.0 Luna, based on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

This is the solution, if someone needs it :

After removing apparmor skype status, you need to reload it manually (it won't do it alone at reboot) :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload
```

And... everything works fine. You could reinstall additionaly sni-qt (in my case, it was indeed removed) and THEN reload apparmor status.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download this icon pack: https://yadi.sk/d/Gk383ScfbF9im and extract to /usr/share/sni-qt/icons/
2. upgrade sni-qt from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~rpeshkov/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
3. Profit!

source: https://github.com/rpeshkov/skype-wrapper/issues/2  “rpeshkov commented on Sep 8”